# Repeat a pattern while using re.sub

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I would like to modify a string that looks like this:

```
...some fruit names... ORANGE ...some fruit names...
```

into something like this:

```
...some fruit names... ORANGE APPLE ...some fruit names...
```

With `sed` I would do something like:

```
sed 's/ORANGE/& APPLE/' <<< $the_string
```

However I don't know how to do this kind of thing with Python's `re` module. Is there a special sign which fonction is equivalent to the `&` of `sed` ? I haven't  found anything like this in the documentation.

So far what I do is to extract the pattern `ORANGE` from the string (to get it's litteral form), append to it the string `APPLE`, and then substitute to `ORANGE` the string that I've formed. But it is very inefficient, and I would like to do the same thing with a single regexp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`re.sub('(ORANGE)',r' \1 APPLE', str)` will do it